# How to disable auto restore option in Visual Studio installer project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have an installer prepared from Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. In my package, there are several libraries. Whenever I rename any of the package components from installation folder and run the app, it automatically restores the missing pieces. But problem is I don't want to do this. Is there a way to disable this?

**EDIT**
I have tried according to the suggestion of PhilDW's answer. But after modifying the component id it shows the following message -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documented way to do this for selected files is to set the Component id to null in the Copmponent table in the MSI file. See ComponentId:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx

Visual Studio does not support null guids (it doesn't expose component guids at all) so you'd need to edit the MSI file with Orca be setting those ids to empty for those files.

Comment: I have tried to edit my .msi in orca but I haven't found any way to edit the fields you mentioned above. Can you please help?

Comment: Maybe your MSI file is read-only (or in a read-only location) but just opwn thw MSI file with Orca, go to Component table, find the correct component, double-click the ComponentID field and delete it.

Comment: I have already tried several time but after modifying it by orca the installer is not runnable.

Comment: That documentation is the MS documentation of how to achieve what you want. If you are unable to perform that change correctly then describe exactly what you did, exactly what error you get that means "not runnable" and maybe then you can be guided correctly. Did you really mark me down bewcause you are unable to do what the documentation describes as the right way to do this?

Comment: I did the same what the doc said. But when I have saved the msi after editing in orca, it is not runnable.

Comment: You are still not explaing "not runnable" and it's not clear that you did the right thing. I've done this exact thing with a VS 2013 generated MSI and it does what you want. It installs the file but does not restore it on a repair, as the documentation says. Therefore you must be doing it incorrectly if the MSI works fine without your change. You nullify that guid in ComponentId for the file in the Component table when you find the right one.

Comment: Yes I am doing incorrectly indeed. But what is the correct way? I have just edited the component id to null and saved it. Then I tried to run, after that it shows the message implying that the installation package could not be opened. Please check my edited question.

Comment: That just looks like you have saved it with Orca but not shut down Orca. The message simply means that the MSI file is in use.

Comment: No. I have closed the orca before running the msi.

Comment: As I have said time and time, I haven't modified anything except changing the component GUID.